# How to preserve the order of a vector in a table in R?

Tags: r, sorting

Pretty simple question, I assume. I am trying to do this for a different type of object (with class 'acf' and type 'list'), but I assume the answer is easily extendable for a vector (class numeric, type 'double'):

```
 x<-c(4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 10, 15)
 table(x)
 x
 1  2  4  5  6 10 15 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I would like the output of the table to be in the same order as the vector (4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 10, 15). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want this?  What if there are two 4s, four 2s, etc?  How would you order it then?

Comment: Try `table(factor(x, levels=unique(x)))`

Comment: @RichardScriven My original problem is with objects derived from the Autocorrelation/Partial Autocorrelation Functions in a Time Series. Whether there are two 4s, four 2s, would be irrelevant, as in this case, the vector represents the strength of the lag in position _k_. A sorted table, decreasing or increasing, is of little use when the positions are mismatched.

Comment: That is information that should be included in the question.  Include all relevant information needed to solve the problem.  As of right now, it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @akrun managed to solve the question. When I accepted the answer, it was deleted. It was only now that I noted there was a comment for it. The information provided for the question is the minimal required to reproduce the example. The behavior of both type of objects described, when applied to a table, is the same: the output is sorted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 table(factor(x, levels=unique(x)))
```